# NextJS / Supabase Auth - How do I refresh Discord provider_token / access token properly

Tags: javascript, session, next.js, oauth-2.0, supabase

currently I am running into the following problem. I have a NextJs 13 project and I'm handling my authentication using Supabase Auth.

Currently I am just working with the Discord provider and everything is working. But **after some minutes** the session object is getting updated and the **provider_token** is set tu **null**.

I am authenticating via :

```js
supabaseClient.auth.signInWithOAuth({
   provider: 'discord',
       options: {
           scopes: 'identify guilds'
       }
  })
```

This is a part of the session object.

The Supabase Session is not getting reset, its just the "provider session" aka. Discord Session.

The Discord access_token is named "provider_token" in the supabase session.

```
provider_refresh_token: null
provider_token: null
refresh_token: "XXXXXX"
token_type: "bearer"
```

Is there any "best practice" to handle this problem in NextJS using supabase?

thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Supabase auth uses your provider token for initial account creation, and does not issue or refresh a new one once the signup process is done. If you want to keep a fresh access token for your OAuth provider, you would have to do so manually by yourself using the `provider_token` and `provider_refresh_token` you obtain from the initial signup.